# Ruby cucumber and Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have feature files in cucumber ,for its step definition I am using Ruby-selenium.I am trying to integrate with my local Jenkins but I am unable to do the same.
Any headsup how to proceed

Comment: Can you be more specific about the nature of your problem?  How have you set up your Jenkins job and what error do you get when you try to run it?

Comment: Can you please mention your set up process and where did you go wrong along with the error message?

Comment: Actually @russthegibbon , I have used the shell script as bundle exec rake jenkins:regression[../.../....] ,the build is successful but it is not trigeering any testcases under the regression tag

Comment: Could be a problem with your rakefile maybe.  Does it work if you just set up your job to run `cucumber -t @regression`?

Comment: its not working

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @AyanHaldar Need more details please; add your rake file..

Answer (score 0):

When things about Jenkins, it is mostly about Environment Variables. I recommend you to check if your local env vars are correctly passed to Jenkins.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).